# Numerically integrating a 2-form over a triangulated MeshRegion surface

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, mesh

I'd like to integrate a 2-form of the form $adx\wedge dy+bdy\wedge dz+cdz\wedge dx$ over a MeshRegion, which is topologically a compact surface with boundary.

Can Mathematica compute it automatically? The only way in my mind is to compute a normal vector of unit length for each triangle and replace the 2-form with a multiple of the volume form of the triangle on each point in the triangle, and then sum up.

Besides, how should I tell Mathematica the orientation of the surface? The surface is obtained from TriangulateMesh and I have a specified orientation of the boundary, given by ordering points on the boundary.

I know that there is a function

```
Integrate[f, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh]
```

which computes the integration of $f(x,y,z)$ times the volume form over the surface, but the $f$ here is too hard to compute.

[image]

Comment: I guess that's not built in, one will have to implement themselves. To do that in differential form, I found [Keenan Crane](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kmcrane/)'s *CS 15-458/858: Discrete Differential Geometry* is a very good starting point, where algorithms and data structures are discussed in detail, side-by-side along with corresponding exterior calculus concepts.

Comment: @Silvia Thanks. I've already written such a function mentioned above and it works well……

Comment: Nice! You do know our site encourages people answering their own questions right? :)

Comment: @Silvia I've posted the codes together with a small example :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my solution. The 2-form is $\mu=\mu_1dy \wedge dz + \mu_2dz \wedge dx+\mu_3 dx \wedge dy$, where $\{\mu_1, \mu_2, \mu_3\}$ is

$$
\left\{\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{x}{2 \left(y^2-1\right) \left(x^2+y^2-1\right)}+\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{y^2-1}}\right)}{2 \left(y^2-1\right)^{3/2}}\right),\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{y}{2 \left(x^2-1\right) \left(x^2+y^2-1\right)}+\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right)}{2 \left(x^2-1\right)^{3/2}}\right),0\right\}. 
$$

For an oriented triangle with vertices $a,b,c$, construct a parametrization

```
paratriangle[a_, b_, c_, co1_, co2_] :=
 a + (b - a)*co1 + (c - a)*co2
```

$\{\partial x/\partial u,\partial y/\partial u,\partial z/\partial u\}$ is

```
D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3, u, v], u]
```

Now we pull back the forms and get

dy wedge dz = (D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3,u,v],u][[2]]*D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3,u,v],v][[3]]
-D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3,u,v],v][[2]]*D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3,u,v],u][[3]])
du wedge dv

dz wedge dx= (D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3,u,v],u][[3]]*D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3,u,v],v][[1]] - D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3,u,v],u][[1]]*D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3,u,v],v][[3]])
du wedge dv

dx wedge dy=(D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3,u,v],u][[1]]*D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3,u,v],v][[2]]
-D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3,u,v],u][[2]]*D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3,u,v],v][[1]])
du wedge dv

Assume the pullback of $\mu$ is $coeff \ du \wedge dv$. Then

```
coeff=mu1* (D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3,u,v],u][[2]]*D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3,u,v],v][[3]]
-D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3,u,v],v][[2]]*D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3,u,v],u][[3]])
 + mu2*(D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3,u,v],u][[3]]*D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3,u,v],v][[1]]
- D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3,u,v],u][[1]]*D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3,u,v],v][[3]])
+mu3 *(D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3,u,v],u][[1]]*D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3,u,v],v][[2]]
-D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3,u,v],u][[2]]*D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3,u,v],v][[1]])
```

Let

```
standardtri = Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}]
```

We need to Integrate[coeff,{u,v}[Element]standardtri].

```
coeff[vertex1_, vertex2_, vertex3_] := Module[{vert1 = vertex1
   , vert2 = vertex2
   , vert3 = vertex3
   , mu1val, mu2val, mu3val},
  mu1val = mu1 /. {x -> paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3, u, v][[1]],
     y -> paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3, u, v][[2]],
     z -> paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3, u, v][[3]]};
  mu2val = mu2 /. {x -> paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3, u, v][[1]],
     y -> paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3, u, v][[2]],
     z -> paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3, u, v][[3]]};
  mu3val = mu3 /. {x -> paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3, u, v][[1]],
     y -> paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3, u, v][[2]],
     z -> paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3, u, v][[3]]};
  mu1val*(D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3, u, v], u][[2]]*
       D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3, u, v], v][[3]] - 
      D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3, u, v], v][[2]]*
       D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3, u, v], u][[3]])
   + mu2val*(D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3, u, v], u][[3]]*
       D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3, u, v], v][[1]] - 
      D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3, u, v], u][[1]]*
       D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3, u, v], v][[3]])
   + mu3val*(D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3, u, v], u][[1]]*
       D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3, u, v], v][[2]] - 
      D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3, u, v], u][[2]]*
       D[paratriangle[vert1, vert2, vert3, u, v], v][[1]])
  ]
```

Now let's work out an example checking the Stokes' theorem.

Take the tetrahedra with vertices {0,0,0},{0.5,0,0},{0,0.5,0},{0,0,0.5}.

```
Integrate[
  coeff[{0.5, 0, 0}, {0, 0.5, 0}, {0, 0, 0.5}], {u, v} \[Element] 
   standardtri] - 
 Integrate[
  coeff[{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0.5, 0}, {0, 0, 0.5}], {u, v} \[Element] 
   standardtri] + 
 Integrate[
  coeff[{0, 0, 0}, {0.5, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.5}], {u, v} \[Element] 
   standardtri] - 
 Integrate[
  coeff[{0, 0, 0}, {0.5, 0, 0}, {0, 0.5, 0}], {u, v} \[Element] 
   standardtri]
```

we get

```
0.0232213
```

Define volfunc[x, y, z] to be $\frac{1}{\left(x^2+y^2-1\right)^2}$.

```
Simplify[D[mu1, x] + D[mu2, y] + D[mu3, z]] == volfunc[x, y, z]
```

returns True.

```
NIntegrate[
 volfunc[x, y, z], {x, y, z} \[Element] 
  Tetrahedron[{{0, 0, 0}, {0.5, 0, 0}, {0, 0.5, 0}, {0, 0, 0.5}}]]
```

we get

```
0.0232213
```

as expected.